# ng-select-ng-select has no exported member 'NG_SELECT_DEFAULT_CONFIG'

Tags: angular-ngselect

Migrating to the latest package results in the build error.

```
ERROR in src/app/global.module.ts:106:13 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NG_SELECT_DEFAULT_CONFIG'.

106         provide: NG_SELECT_DEFAULT_CONFIG,
```

```
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_SELECT_DEFAULT_CONFIG,
            useValue: {
                notFoundText: 'Not found',
                loadingText: 'Processing',
                placeholder: 'Please input'
            }
        }
    ]
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

NG_SELECT_DEFAULT_CONFIG was removed. You can set the config by injection NgSelectConfig.

```
  constructor(private config: NgSelectConfig) {
    this.config.notFoundText = 'Custom not found';
    this.config.loadingText = 'Custom loadingText';
    this.config.placeholder = 'Custom placeholder';
  }
```

There's also an example on there github page:
https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select